# sed not replacing as expected

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Why I am getting the same output as the input while I am expecting 'search replace subject' as output:

```
x="search='some thing' replace='something' subject=/path"

echo $x
echo "$x" | sed 's/\(\w+\)=/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: `\w+` is extended regex, you have to use `-r` option with `sed`. If you do, you also don't need to escape the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `sed` uses old-style regular expressions. If you want new style (aka "extended") regular expressions you should use `sed -r`. And anyway you are using a mixture of old-style and new style regular expressions which will never work (you cannot have at the same time `\(`...`\)` and `+`); so either

```
sed -e 's/\(\w\+\)=/\1\n/g'
```

or

```
sed -re 's/(\w+)=/\1\n/g'
```

Any of the above would produce

```
search
'some thing' replace
'something' subject
/path
```

If you are actually expecting the output to be `search replace subject` then

```
sed -re "s/=('[^']*'|[^']\\S*)//g"
```

That is, delete all matches of an equal sign followed either by

- `'` any number of non-`'` and a final `'`, *or*
- a sequence of 1 or more non-blanks starting with anything but `'`.

(But this has nothing to do with the regex in the original question. I cannot relate the desired output with the regex in the question.)

Comment: I am literally expecting "search replace subject" as output.

Comment: @AdamSilver: See updated answer. However, there is no relationship between this desired output and the regex in the question; the regex in the question seems to want to split the input into multiple lines -- or else, what was the `\n` in the replacement string supposed to do? The desired output wants to delete some parts of the input, so the replacement string is expected to be empty.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. This is what I wanted.